# mysql ERROR 1205: 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, optimization

***This is a replica of my StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42509436/3963249)***

I am trying to update a row on a specific table of my database.

```
UPDATE `Search`.`credentials` SET `status`='0' WHERE `id`='30';
```

and i am getting the error

```
ERROR 1205: 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction  
SQL Statement: UPDATE `Search`.`credentials` SET `status`='0' WHERE `id`='30'
```

I have set the timeout to 200

`show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';`

> +----------------------------------+-------+
>   |  Variable_name                              | Value|
>   +----------------------------------+-------+ 
>   | innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50       |
>   +----------------------------------+-------+

The database is been used, but not all the time, and not the table I want to update

`mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;`

> +-----------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------+
>  |Database| Table
>                          
>   | In_use | Name_locked |
>   +-----------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------+
>  | db1          | PayInformation 
>            |2
>           |
>   0                      
>   |
>  | db1          | KeyMapping             
>   |      4        |
>   0                      
>   |
>  | db1          | NoticeInformation
>       |      2
>           |
>   0                      
>   |
>  | Search  |
>   companies               
>   |      1         |
>   0                      
>   |
>  | db1          |
>   ContractInformation |      5
>           |
>   0                      
>   |
>   +----------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------+

some times there are more lines concerning the Search database, but none that is using the same table that i need to update.

and from the process list i get

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where db="afmSearch";
```

> +----+------+-------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------+
>  |  ID  |  USER  |  HOST     
>      |  DB          |
>    COMMAND  |  TIME  |  STATE  |
>    INFO  |
>   +----+------+-------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------+
>  |  xx  |  me      |  my.ip:44604
>    |  Search  |  Sleep      
>    |        1  |      
>          |  NULL  |
>   +----+------+-------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Some other connection was running something really long - probably longer than 50 seconds.

Possibly another connection is in `autocommit=0` mode, but just sitting there, forgetting to do a `COMMIT`.

If you can, get the `PROCESSLIST` before it times out.  Also do `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;`

Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE credentials`.  Look for other writes to that table, and check for index usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (probable) turned out to be that i didnt close a ResultSet, inside Java. The strange thing is that MySql was not informing me that someone was using that table at all! Let alone that I thought results sets are closed when the method they are in is terminated. apparently not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try see if your MySQL Server had a process in running.

To see that, run the command on MySQL Client:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

See **id**, **state** and **info** columns and analyze the problem. After you find the problem, kill the process with:

```
KILL <PROCESS ID>;
```